# Add This - Shares vs Clicks

Tags: social-media, addthis

Using AddThis can someone please explain what the differences is if someone shares but does not click what does that mean?

EX: I have 10 Shares and 7 clicks.  What does that mean?

Also what does it mean when something has "Viral Lift"

Thanks for any info provided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [Viral lift is the percentage increase in traffic due to shares and clicks](http://www.addthis.com/blog/2011/02/17/how-viral-is-your-content/#.Tm8LidRSpBl) Essentially, viral lift shows you how viral your content is – if your shares are getting a lot of clicks, your viral lift percentage will be high.

More at the link.

As for the click/share discrepancy, have you enabled [address bar sharing](http://www.addthis.com/help/address-bar-sharing-analytics#.Tm8MhdRSpBk)? That would be at least one way you could generate more shares than actual clicks.